# Fading out/in images using chained JavaScript Promises

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I'm trying to create a non-JQuery image slideshow, where the images fade in/out based on a timer.  After a ton of research today, I believe that JavaScript's Promise functionality can do this, but it's not quite right...

My problem is that the fade in and fade out functions appear to be happening at the same time, so the image just flickers.  I'm trying to adapt some of the many examples of using `then()` to chain the functions, but obviously something is wrong.

My logic was to:

1. Show the initial image on page load (via a CSS rule)
2. Fade out
3. Changing the background image URL
4. Fade in

My [online example is here](https://codepen.io/evildr/pen/BXBzPy), and the JavaScript is here:

```
// Background images to show
var arr_Images = [
    'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/08/24/12/53/banner-904884_960_720.jpg',
    'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/11/19/22/52/coding-1841550_960_720.jpg',
    'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/05/27/23/32/matrix-356024_960_720.jpg'
];

var cycleImage = document.getElementById("cycleImage");

// Preload images
for(x = 0; x < arr_Images.length; x++)
{
  var img = new Image();
    img.src = arr_Images[x];
}

function fadeOutPromise(element, nextBgImgUrl) {
    console.log("Fading out");
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        var op = 1;  // initial opacity
        var timer1 = setInterval(function () {
            if (op <= 0.1){
                clearInterval(timer1);
                element.style.display = 'none';
                cycleImage.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + nextBgImgUrl + "')";
            }
            element.style.opacity = op;
            element.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + op * 100 + ")";
            op -= op * 0.1;
        }, 100);
        resolve("Faded In");
    });
}

function fadeInPromise(element) {
    console.log("Fading in");
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        var op = 0.1;  // initial opacity
        element.style.display = 'block';
        var timer2 = setInterval(function () {
            if (op >= 1){
                clearInterval(timer2);
            }
            element.style.opacity = op;
            element.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + op * 100 + ")";
            op += op * 0.1;
        }, 10); 
        resolve("Faded Out");
    });
}

function slideShow() {

    // Loop background image using array
    var i = 0;
    var delay = 3000;

    // Loop
    let imageLoopTimer = setTimeout(function tick() {

        fadeOutPromise(cycleImage, arr_Images[i]).then(
            fadeInPromise(cycleImage).then(function() {
                i++;
                if ( i >= arr_Images.length) { i = 0; }
                imageLoopTimer = setTimeout(tick, delay);               
            })
        );

    }, delay);

}

slideShow();
```

Can somebody first explain what's wrong, then provide a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setInterval()` is running as a background task therefore `resolve()` will be fired right after the initialization of `timer2`.

- Its pretty similar to running an `async` operation, but not `awaiting`
  it.
- Or with promises it would be like calling a `function` that returns a `Promise`, but wanting to access the data without a `.then()` callback

You need to resolve your promise inside the `if (op >= 1)` part for it to be actually resolved **after** the fadeIn/Out happened.

Check [this snippet](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KOPvrR) for an updated version of yours. The Promises are resolved inside the `setInterval()`.

Here is the relevant JavaScript code of it as a direct snippet:

```
function fadeOutPromise(element, nextBgImgUrl) {
    console.log("Fading out"+i);
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        element.style.opacity = 0;
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log("Fading out done"+i);
            element.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + nextBgImgUrl + "')";
            resolve();
        }, 1000);
    });
}

function fadeInPromise(element) {
    console.log("Fading in"+i);
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        element.style.opacity = 1;
        setTimeout(resolve, 1000);
    });
}

var i = 0;
var delay = 3000;

function slideShow() {

    // Loop background image using array

    // Loop
    let imageLoopTimer = setTimeout(() => tick(), delay);

}

function tick() {

    fadeOutPromise(cycleImage, arr_Images[i]).then(() =>
        fadeInPromise(cycleImage).then(function() {
            i++;
            if ( i >= arr_Images.length) { i = 0; }
            imageLoopTimer = setTimeout(() => tick(), delay);               
        })
    );

}
```

## Edit (with transition opacity)

I have [edited the snippet](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KOPvrR?editors=1111) and now it works with transition on opacity.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  However, two weird issues remain.  In Firefox, the fading is hideously flickering, and in Chrome the image just randomly shows/hides.  Can you shed any light on the latter specifically?

Comment: @EvilDr Every browser has its own rendering engine, so it can be different. Also, it might be a browser version thing. I use Chrome 75.0 and there is no flickering for me except for the first image. To avoid flickering I would suggest you to use jQuery animations or even better native CSS animations. CSS will be the smoothest, because they are heavily optimized. Also, you could remove a lot of JavaScript code, by using CSS animations and classes.

Comment: @EvilDr Chek the updated version. It now works with transition opacity.

Comment: Excellent, thank you.  Can you explain the random thing in Firefox where sometimes the image just appears/disappears.  Its totally intermittent.  Do you know if there's a more CSS-focused way to solve this that might be easier on memory?

Answer (score 3):

You are almost there. The problem is how you resolve your promises. 
What you intent to do in fade functions is:
- Create a promise
- Execute the logic with intervals
- Resolve promise

But you resolve the promise immediately, whereas you should resolve your promise once fade operation is done:

```
function fadeInPromise(element) {
    console.log("Fading in");
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        var op = 0.1;  // initial opacity
        element.style.display = 'block';
        var timer2 = setInterval(function () {
            if (op >= 1){
                clearInterval(timer2);
                resolve():  // Fade is done here
            }
            element.style.opacity = op;
            element.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + op * 100 + ")";
            op += op * 0.1;
        }, 10); 
    });
}
```

And same thing in fadeout

**Another tip for flickering**
You should not change opacity that often if you want smooth effects. In css, there is already 'transition' property. So you should instead do something like this with transition:
- Show image with opacity 1
- Set opactiy to 0
- After  ms, change url and set opacity to 1

Comment: You've just described my entire day's struggle with your "another tip".  Despite adding the `resolve` amendments, the flickering is truly awful, and in Chrome the image just randomly disappears.  I tried using CSS with `transition: opacity` earlier, but could not get that to work either.  If you can help there, I would be extremely grateful.

Comment: I created a codepen for your example https://codepen.io/dogancanarabaci/pen/YmKrLx. Comments should be explaining it well. The async await part is just a new way of using promises. Instead of writing it with .then, you can just use async await

Comment: That's a lot better, thank you.  In Chrome it looks great, but in Firefox it looks dreadful.  Is that an issue with the timers and memory usage?  Can it be fixed?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure what looks bad in firefox :) I just tried on macos and it looks same. Also remember that fading in and out this big images is a costly operation. But depending on your system it might be an issue with event queue. You might use requestAnimationFrame before doing any style changes. I updated my codepen with requestAnimationFrame, but as I said, i still cannot see any difference